# How can I login to the site using requests module in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to login to the site below using requests module in python.

https://accounts.dmm.com/service/login/password

But I cannot find the "login_id" and "password" fields in the requests' response.

I CAN find them using "Inspect" menu in Chrome.

```
<input type="text" name="login_id" id="login_id" placeholder="メールアドレス" value="">
```

and

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="パスワード" value="">
```

I tried to find them in the response from requests, but couldn't.
Here is my code:

```
import requests  
url = 'https://accounts.dmm.com/service/login/password'
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)
with open('test_saved_login.html','w',encoding="utf-8")as file:
  file.write(response.text) # Neither "login_id" nor "password" field found in the file.
```

How should I do?
Selenium is an easy solution, but I do not want to use it.

Comment: better use tab `Network` instead of `Inspect` and see what browser sends to server when you press button `Login`. And then you have to do the same with `requests`. If server use `POST` then you have to also use `requests.post()`. If it send some data then you have to send the same data in `post(..., payload=...)`. But if page uses JavaScript to generate some value then it can be problem because `requests`/`beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. And then better use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which let you control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I couldn't find POST line in Network tab. As you and David mention the page uses JavaScript. Thank you @furas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login form is created with javascript. Try viewing the page in a browser with javascript disabled there will be no form. The people who control that site are trying to prevent people from doing exactly what you're trying to do. In addition to the fact the form elements don't appear (which really doesn't matter with requests,) they are also using a special token that you won't be able to guess which I expect is also in obfuscated javascript. So it is likely impracticable to script a login with requests and unless you have special permission from this company it is highly inadvisable that you continue with doing what you're trying to do.